# C# Can't find checkbox in Controls (System.Web.UI.Control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, checkbox, controls

I'm trying to select the drawings that a user made, so I start like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox checkb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
    DropForm.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>Desenho "+ (i +1) +":  "));
    DropForm.Controls.Add(checkb);
    Button1.Visible = true;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

And when the user clicks the button:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (System.Web.UI.Control control in DropForm.Controls)
    {
        if (control is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)
        {
            if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)control).Checked == true)
            {
                Response.Write("Yes");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("no");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("cicle");
        }
     }
 }
```

I have 13 Controls on the page so it shows 13 'cicle', but it's not recognizing any checkbox, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem could be because of you're creating CheckBox controls dynamically. To circumvent this problem you will have to recreate the same set of controls again on Page_Load event on ButtonClick postback event wherein they can process their state.

Comment: Can you show me how? Do I just run the code inside button1 in another page? How?

Comment: No additional page is required. Every page will go through Page_Load event cycle during which you may want to recreate the Checkbox controls once again, mostly check for IsPostBack property so that you won't create them on the normal load and keep your existing logic intact.

Comment: Oh I think i understand, but can you explain a bit further on Recreate the checkbox controls?

Comment: You're creating the checkboxes dynamically which were not present at the time of Load event. The same will hold good when the page is Posted back for event handling. Here something has changed on the client side (Browser) like Checked state which needs to be restored for you to write logic something like you've done in case of Button click handler.

Comment: Once you create the checkboxes with same Ids, ASP.NET will be able to set control state from ViewState during Load. Read [Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=hL3Qp0zRBOc&ranSiteID=hL3Qp0zRBOc-ts_tOr96BASCbq3caWBSQg&tduid=(23c32c15be19e2de1f8ab105d1ce7102)(256380)(2459594)(hL3Qp0zRBOc-ts_tOr96BASCbq3caWBSQg)()#lifecycle_events) for good understanding

Comment: I tried some things but they didn't work, can you show me what you mean more exactly?

Comment: I don't have a sample code to present. Let me build something

Comment: In the mean time you can refer to these reference [ASP.NET Dynamic Control ViewState](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack.aspx) [Retaining State for Dynamic Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i)